# PHP SQL not passing sum parameters

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i have following script

```
select left(m.last_local_call_time,10) as date
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.el_fa="ano" then 1 else 0 end) as elfa
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" then 1 else 0 end) as zaujem
,sum(case when m.status="NI" then 1 else 0 end) as nezaujem
,sum(case when m.status="INAOS" then 1 else 0 end) as inaos
,sum(case when m.status="NK" then 1 else 0 end) as nk
,sum(case when m.status="ADC" then 1 else 0 end) as adc
,sum(case when m.status="CBHOLD" or m.status="CALLBK" then 1 else 0 end) as cb
,sum(case when m.status="N" or m.status="NA" then 1 else 0 end) as na
,sum(case when m.status="A" or m.status="B" then 1 else 0 end) as odk
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.HBO_balik="on" and o.Zaujem_o_sluzbu_HBO_na_="záujem o službu – 24 mesiacov" then 1 else 0 end) as hbo24
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.HBO_balik="on" and o.Zaujem_o_sluzbu_HBO_na_="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as hbobv
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.Maxi_____viazanost_na_24_mesiacov="on" and o.Zaujem_o_maxi="záujem o službu – 24 mesiacov" then 1 else 0 end) as maxi24
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.Maxi_____viazanost_na_24_mesiacov="on" and o.Zaujem_o_maxi="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as maxibv
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.extra_sport_plus="on" and o.zaujem_o_extra_sport_plus="záujem o službu – 24 mesiacov" then 1 else 0 end) as sp24
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.extra_sport_plus="on" and o.zaujem_o_extra_sport_plus="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as spbv
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.extra_hu_plus="on" and o.zaujem_o_extra_hu_plus="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as hpbv
from db_DIGI_upsell_20160711_ o
join vicidial_list m on o.lead_id = m.lead_id where m.last_local_call_time is not NULL
group by left(m.last_local_call_time,10) DESC;
```

In heidiSQL everything looks fine, but when i run it with my php script

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('ip', 'user', 'pw', 'db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, 'select left(m.last_local_call_time,10) as date
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.el_fa="ano" then 1 else 0 end) as elfa
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" then 1 else 0 end) as zaujem
,sum(case when m.status="NI" then 1 else 0 end) as nezaujem
,sum(case when m.status="INAOS" then 1 else 0 end) as inaos
,sum(case when m.status="NK" then 1 else 0 end) as nk
,sum(case when m.status="ADC" then 1 else 0 end) as adc
,sum(case when m.status="CBHOLD" or m.status="CALLBK" then 1 else 0 end) as cb
,sum(case when m.status="N" or m.status="NA" then 1 else 0 end) as na
,sum(case when m.status="A" or m.status="B" then 1 else 0 end) as odk
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.HBO_balik="on" and o.Zaujem_o_sluzbu_HBO_na_="záujem o službu – 24 mesiacov" then 1 else 0 end) as hbo24
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.HBO_balik="on" and o.Zaujem_o_sluzbu_HBO_na_="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as hbobv
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.Maxi_____viazanost_na_24_mesiacov="on" and o.Zaujem_o_maxi="záujem o službu – 24 mesiacov" then 1 else 0 end) as maxi24
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.Maxi_____viazanost_na_24_mesiacov="on" and o.Zaujem_o_maxi="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as maxibv
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.extra_sport_plus="on" and o.zaujem_o_extra_sport_plus="záujem o službu – 24 mesiacov" then 1 else 0 end) as sp24
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.extra_sport_plus="on" and o.zaujem_o_extra_sport_plus="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as spbv
,sum(case when m.status="ZP" and o.extra_hu_plus="on" and o.zaujem_o_extra_hu_plus="záujem o službu – bez viazanosti" then 1 else 0 end) as hpbv
from db_DIGI_upsell_20160711_ o
join vicidial_list m on o.lead_id = m.lead_id where m.last_local_call_time is not NULL
group by left(m.last_local_call_time,10) DESC;');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   { echo $row['date'];
     echo $row['hbo24'];
     echo $row['hbobv'];
     echo $row['maxi24'];
     echo $row['maxibv'];
     echo $row['sp24'];
     echo $row['spbv'];
     echo $row['hpbv'];
     }
```

everything except date is '0' (date is normal '2016-07-12','2016-07-13')

In HeidiSQL i have numbers.

Can anyone explain it please?

Thanks in advance

## UPDATE 2

```
"date"  "elfa"  "zaujem"    "nezaujem"  "inaos" "nk"    "adc"   "cb"    "na"    "odk"   "hbo24" "hbobv" "maxi24"    "maxibv"    "sp24"  "spbv"  "hpbv"
"2016-07-13"    "16"    "43"    "115"   "2" "2" "86"    "91"    "207"   "22"    "4" "6" "5" "7" "1" "2" "19"
"2016-07-12"    "24"    "53"    "133"   "7" "5" "0" "41"    "5" "18"    "9" "4" "2" "13"    "1" "1" "24"
```

This is result from HEIDI SQL. In PHP everywhere except date there is 0;

Comment: Try replacing `"` with `'` and `'` with `"`

Comment: Hello no change :(

Comment: Why not to run in PHP **the exact query** you had in Heidi?

Comment: If my eyes do not betray me, it is not.

Comment: its only date and datum. I forget to translate datum in my post. But it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have sloved it. It was about charset...

i just made this :

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

And everything works. Since i had utf8 set in php, when i made echo of query it looked ok. But then after some researches i finished with this.

Thanks to all.